# How to use jq to extract keys and print them a certain amount of times depending on another keys value from a JSON file

Tags: json, key, jq

So I'm trying to get the top-level keys and then multiply each one by the amount under each key then post the key as many times as the amount states.

How do I get jq to take json like this:

```
{
"2tMRnry9cMqcMo5JqPWvyFaznoU8ujcf3i9ALpzokFHK": {
    "mints": [
        "Ehmx5dGtUtYSTRYDNptYSPLXs4ZSFmCPHvPd5ProtGPp",
        "DZHynoX1yrwdppnNNZmBHqap89vziSehmhJP3BQESoaN",
        "CVdM8fu474xaVxxuUzLsn7rxTA1mcrkpq8K7YYN4gRoc"
    ],
    "amount": 3
},
"CVjVEB2WBmDACcovpxKAEqXZZKdUGsGAn2v5EsWSjtXX": {
    "mints": [
        "CPBsjXBKrG2QfRAkaPDJ282bXr7uD9259Ymb6EC93jjb"
    ],
    "amount": 1
},
"Cndq2Yjt1MVkQPYiZod9eGZcTHFDhuYjJA7N6vAuVw8H": {
    "mints": [
        "66T698sRaJiyEXu6RrBw8ApNYsx1spkQQZZM9nZdA9EE",
        "65QEUZVWMg12UvrRNcoV5DwVANKWaarHPd52KemV4pRy"
    ],
        "amount": 2
    }
}
```

and generate this output:

```
2tMRnry9cMqcMo5JqPWvyFaznoU8ujcf3i9ALpzokFHK
2tMRnry9cMqcMo5JqPWvyFaznoU8ujcf3i9ALpzokFHK
2tMRnry9cMqcMo5JqPWvyFaznoU8ujcf3i9ALpzokFHK
CVjVEB2WBmDACcovpxKAEqXZZKdUGsGAn2v5EsWSjtXX
Cndq2Yjt1MVkQPYiZod9eGZcTHFDhuYjJA7N6vAuVw8H
Cndq2Yjt1MVkQPYiZod9eGZcTHFDhuYjJA7N6vAuVw8H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_entries` to access key and value, and `range` to iterate:

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | range(.value.amount) as $_ | .key'
```

```
2tMRnry9cMqcMo5JqPWvyFaznoU8ujcf3i9ALpzokFHK
2tMRnry9cMqcMo5JqPWvyFaznoU8ujcf3i9ALpzokFHK
2tMRnry9cMqcMo5JqPWvyFaznoU8ujcf3i9ALpzokFHK
CVjVEB2WBmDACcovpxKAEqXZZKdUGsGAn2v5EsWSjtXX
Cndq2Yjt1MVkQPYiZod9eGZcTHFDhuYjJA7N6vAuVw8H
Cndq2Yjt1MVkQPYiZod9eGZcTHFDhuYjJA7N6vAuVw8H
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ozwFXfLTrku)

Comment: Thanks for the help pmf. 
How would you go by outputting the same result but with double quotation marks an the beginning and ending of each line?

Comment: @Mad If you want to output JSON strings, just drop the `-r` option